# Xmlrpc is vulnerable to xxe attack?

Tags: php, xml, security, web, xml-rpc

May be this is out of the topic but it is important aspect for me, so i am now asking to you guys,

I have a website contains the **xmlrpc.php** file then **Is it vulnerable to the xxe attack** like if any one can pull out all the methods by using the **system.listMethods.** Hope you understand what i am talking about. How an attacker can exploit it?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In default settings, XMLRPC is not vulnerable in Java and Python against XXE attacks. You can check it here;
http://www.securiteam.com/securitynews/6D0100A5PU.html

Comment: But what about of the PHP? @Umut ERGİN